# hardware menu button override for redirecting to page

Tags: android, menu

is possible overade hardware menu button? When i tap on hardware menu button, appear new layout page, instead of view of submenu? My basic app do not have any setting  so only what i want is credits page. I try lot of options. I mean something like this:

```
@override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu() {
setContentView(R.layout.credits); }
```

Every help would be great.

Comment: Please, notify that not every device has the hardware menu button.

Comment: As it currently stands, it is unclear how this is supposed to solve OPs question, or what you're even suggesting. Would you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 0):

From option menu You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

So you can use

```
@override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu() {
    setContentView(R.layout.credits); 
    return false;
}
```